# FFmpeg concat - remove source files

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg

I have a folder with ~100 `.ts` mpegts files. I need to concat them together while removing the files as soon as they are joined.

I need to list files > join file #1 and #2 > delete #1 > repeat.. How do I write it?

`for f in *.ts; do ffmpeg <what here?>; rm $f; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found a way to do it without FFmpeg:

```
find tsfolder -name '*.ts' | while read filename; do cat "$filename" >> tsfolder/out.tmp; rm "$filename"; done
```

- `find tsfolder` : folder `tsfolder` contains mpegts `.ts` files
- `do cat "$filename" >> tsfolder/out.tmp`: appends the current file provided by `find` to the end of `tsfolder/out.tmp`
- `rm "$filename"`: removes the current file

## Example:

```
$ ls tsfolder
20170125.ts   20170126.ts   20170127.ts
$ find tsfolder -name '*.ts' | while read filename; do cat "$filename" >> tsfolder/out.tmp; rm "$filename"; done
$ ls tsfolder
out.tmp
```

## Tip:

- Use `-maxdepth 1` to ignore subdirectories
- And `-type f` to affect files only

Comment: It is useful if you have a limited storage space on your machine and you can't concat without removing some files first.